# Problem with numerical series

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series is
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\pi* \arctan(i^2)}}$$
I can just say that it not converges because it does not satisfy the necessary condition for convergence?
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{1}{\pi* \arctan(x^2)}=\frac{2}{\pi^2} $$

Comment: What's the question...? If it was whether you can say that: yes, you can...and it is right.

Comment: And if $i=0$, it didn't exist right?

Comment: Yes, you get it.

Comment: A *necessary*, but **insufficient** condition for convergence of the partial sums of a sequence $\{a_n\}$ is that the terms tend to zero - $a_n\to 0\text{ as }n\to\infty.$